# Publishing website solution - How to stop a deleted file from being regenerated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis, visual-web-developer

I have a website solution in Visual Web Developer. I have replaced a new file with an **older** file of the same name. I understand that the default behavior for web deploy is to update only older files with new ones. However, in this case I have replaced the new one with the old one by right clicking it (the old one) and clicking 'publish myfile'. This did in fact save the old file as I want.

The problem begins when I later publish the whole website again (to update other files). Somehow - this older file, which I want on the server, is replaced with the newer version - the one that at least theoretically, doesn't exist neither in my files, nor on the server! Where does it come from? And how can I stop that from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution, though not *why* the problem exists.

Open the folder and make a copy of the file. Then, in solution explorer - delete the original. Publish. Rename the copy to the original name. Publish again.

There may be unnecessary steps here. I'm just posting something that worked.